# Using std::function with inherited classes

Tags: c++, functional-programming, stl

I've had a little issue with some functional callbacks. How does one define a function so that I can have an f of derived x, and assign it to a derived, but given the function object wants the base class.
Can this be done? It makes sense logically. Perhaps I'm missing some form of pointer usage?

This is a simplified form of the actual software I'm working as a base reproducible.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class base {
public:
 std::function<void(base*)> foo;    
};

class derived : public base {
public:
//EDIT:Would this work?
 std::function<void(derived*)> foo;
 int bar = 0;
};

void f(derived* x)
{
    x->bar++;
}

int main()
{
   derived d;
   d.foo = f; //Issue no matching operator, LHS std::function<void(base)> , RHS void(derived)   

   d.foo(&d); //No match for call to std::function<void(base)>
   std::cout << d.bar;
}
```

EDIT: fixed the invocation because silly mistake, also tweaked it slightly on what may work?

Comment: think about if you pass `derived2` to `foo`

Comment: In your call `d.foo();` you are missing the argument. Also `function<void(base)>` means that the function object should be callable with a `base` object, but the function you try to assign it expects a `derived` object. How do you get a `derived` object from a `base` object? Something isn't right in that logic.

Comment: your error message no longer match the code... especially, now you have 2 foo members...

Comment: Just because you are using `std::function` doesn’t mean you are doing “functional programming.”  Why do you add that tag?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand fully what you want, but the call

```
  d.foo();
```

doesn't work because it takes an argument of type base.You can work around that by defining `foo` to not take an argument.

```
class base {
public:
 std::function<void(void)> foo; 
};
```

The call in main then has to be rewritten as

```
int main()
{
   derived d;
   d.foo = [&d]{ f(d); };
   ...
}
```

which works, but may not be what you intended. See live example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/404637221775bf00);